# Как в ListView с наполнителем SimpleAdapter добавить дополнительные виджеты на выбранный Item?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout, getview

Всем добрый день!
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Имеется `ListView`, заполнение которого происходит посредством `SimpleAdapter`.
Мне необходимо, чтобы при щелчке на определенный элемент`ListView`, он изменил свою разметку, то есть, как я понимаю, заменить layout и назначить для конкретного элемента списка другой адаптер.

Мучаюсь уж третий день, но ничего путевого не выходит. 
Знаю, что нужно использовать `getView()` и `LayoutInflater`, но, опять же, туплю, и ничего не выходит. Думал, может есть какие нибудь селекторы для этих целей, которые сами автоматом заменяют `Layout`, но ничего не нашел, хотя, может это вообще мне приснилось(селекторы лайоутов).

Вкратце должно выглядеть как на рисунке.

Положение 1: элемент списка в до нажатия.

Положение 2: следовательно после щелчка по элементу списка.

Рисунок приложить не получилось, он по [ссылке](http://zalil.ru/34734602)

Comment: пиши свой адаптер

Comment: @Gorets и эта мысль меня посещала! Но по тем примерам которые я использовал ничего толкового у меня не получалось. Чувство что статью написал один человек а сотня коряво за ним списала. Даже отдал несколько статей проффесиональным переводчикам, т.к. начал сомневаться в своем понимании английского языка. Как Вы считаете написание собственного адаптера это единственный выход?

Comment: а начните с уроков на [русском](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/). Вам нужны где то с 40 по 50.

Comment: Я их все прочел и не раз, а так же тут developer.alexanderklimov.ru с доступом ко все урокам, а также http://www.cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/

Comment: Если все довольно просто Вы не могли бы показать пример где по шелчку на итем он сменяет свой Layout.

Comment: я когда то уже отвечал на очень похожий вопрос. Никто не меняет по щелчку. При клике по итему Вы просто его помечаете, что он "необычный". И вызываете `notifyDataSetChanged`. Чуточку позже (а для Вас - практически моментально) система сама начнет обновлять листвью (если это нужно). И при этом она сама вызвет метод `geView()`, который и выдаст правильный layout. Как он узнает, что выдать? id элемента ведь известный.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста пример. Пример или реализацию. И можно ссылочку на похожий вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот набросал пример того, как можно сделать. Реализация не претендует на идеальную, но достаточно быстро должна работать.

[Github](https://github.com/rovkinmax/AutoReplaseItemLayout)

Comment: @andreich огромное спасибо. Но теперь при создании собственного лайоута проблема в том, что он не закрывается? Вместо LinearLayout установил Relative и добавил Image View и кнопку. В чем может быть дело? А так огромное спасибо!

Comment: да я не знаю даже. приведите пример, как у вас сделано.

Comment: Я понял! Когда ставишь кнопку и тому подобное, а мультивыбор не включен то кнопка берет на себя клик, надо в методе getView() или в адаптере включить мультивыбор!

Comment: У меня на втором лейоуте есть кнопка и поэтому не реагирует!

Comment: И еще вопрос: когда наполнителем является HashMap<String, Object>, после парсинга JSON файла, а JSON парсится в AsyncTask? Пытаюсь повторить по Вашему примеру с моими дополнениями, но выкидывает NullPointerException

Не могу коомент новый написать!
Вот ниже архив в нем класс который парсит и строит список и Ваши два класса.
http://zalil.ru/34736246

Comment: где именно, код нужен, как вы переписали. я не могу так ничего сказать

Comment: а где ошибки то падает? и я вообще не вижу, где вы используете адаптер. Только мой пример

Answer (score 0):

[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) все верно говорит, в адаптаре сделайте свойство которое хранит номера необычных вью если их много, или просто int если только один вью необычный (например хранить выделенный вью - подсветить его на постоянной основе или еще что то на что фантазии хватит), сделайте public метод изменения данного параметра и в getView сделайте проверку, и если текущей итем "необычный"используйте для него другое view, при клике на вызовете метод адаптера и укажите какой тем считать необычным и перерисуйте

```
........
  int select;

  public void setSelect(int select){
    this.select = select;
  }
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_2colum_1_1, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameGroup);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvBeginEnadNumber);
    Groups item = values.get(position);
    textView.setText(item.getName());
    textView1.setText(item.getMin() + " - " + item.getMax());
    if(position%2 == 0){
        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_color));
        textView1.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_color));

    }
    if(position == select){
        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_select));
        textView1.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_select));
    }

    return rowView;
}

 ........

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    iSelect = position;
    groupsAdapter.setSelect(iSelect);
    listGroups.invalidateViews();
  }
```

как то так

Comment: Попробовал. Работает с теми элементами которые входят в лайоут моей разметки, а как быть с моим случаем? Не выходит! Видимо я уже жестко туплю, но реально что то не получается. У меня задача така что необходимо для выбранного итема заменить один лайоут разметки итема на другой. Вы не могли бы показать это на конкретном примере? То есть есть ListView элементы которого состоят из ImageView и TextView, а при шелчке на конкретный итем его разметка состояла из ImageView, 4-х TextView и одного Button. Буду очень благодарен! Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Выше не могу комментировать. Да только Ваш адаптер. Я хочу вызвать его в MyTask AsyncTask в onPostExecute(), не получается!( Там смысл в том что List должен заполняться из массивов расспарсенных данных или из HashMap, но не получается. Я не могу расширить адаптер для заполнения не только текстом но и Drawable ресурсами, и вызывать заполнение списка не в onCreate() а в onPostExecute(),  а еще лучше в 
onUpdate() AsyncTask

Comment: @Andreich как вы думаете что делать?

Comment: вероятней всего, у вас не правильно построенна модель данных, так как хранить таким образом в HashMap очень неудобно. проще создать класс с такими полями, а переписать под этот класс адаптер, это раз плюнуть

Comment: @vanyamelikov, если нужно, то напишите мне на почту, должна быть видна в профиле

Comment: @Andreich а вы не могли бы в последний раз мне помочь? Правда, пробовал по разному, но как только у меня не стринговский обЪект ни черта не получается. У Вас в профиле только Ваш сайт!